# I keep getting Invalid signature error in NETSUITE

Tags: java, oauth, netsuite, oauth-1.0a

I am trying to login to Netsuite through the API but it keeps giving me the Invalid Signature error. I have checked the other answers and blogs but could not find what is missing. I changed the order and added the parameters manually in the alphabetic order but I still got the same error.
The AccountId contains the '_' symbol while the URL contains the '-' symbol.
Once or twice during random testing it showed invalid timestamp error, but still didn't work and I don't remember exactly what was the error to cause this issue.
i am providing all the required details as input like

1. Token id
2. token secret
3. customer key
4. customer secret
5. Account id
6. URL

Here is my code:

```
public class OAuthSignatureGenerator {

  Encoder encode;

  public String generateOauthHeader(String method, UserFields userFields, String baseUrl) {
    long timestamp = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

    String nonce = getAlphaNumericString();


    ArrayList<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.CONSUMER_KEY + "=" + userFields.getConsumerKey());
    parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.NONCE + "=" + nonce);
    parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.SIGNATURE_METHOD_KEY + "="
    + ApplicationConstants.SIGNATURE_METHOD_VAL);
    parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.TIMESTAMP + "=" + timestamp);
    parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.OAUTH_TOKEN + "=" + userFields.getTokenId());
    parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.VERSION_KEY + "=" + ApplicationConstants.VERSION_VAL);

    /*
     * parameters.add("oauth_consumer_key=\"" + userFields.getConsumerKey()+"\"");
     * parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.NONCE + "=\"" + nonce+"\"");
     * parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.SIGNATURE_METHOD_KEY + "=\"" +
     * ApplicationConstants.SIGNATURE_METHOD_VAL+"\"");
     * parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.TIMESTAMP + "=\"" + timestamp+"\"");
     * parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.OAUTH_TOKEN + "=\"" + userFields.getTokenId()+"\"");
     * parameters.add(ApplicationConstants.VERSION_KEY + "=\"" +
     * ApplicationConstants.VERSION_VAL+"\"");
     */

    Collections.sort(parameters);

    StringBuffer parametersList = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
      parametersList.append(((i > 0) ? "&" : "") + parameters.get(i));
    }

    String signature = null;
    try {
      String signatureString = method + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(baseUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
      + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(parametersList.toString(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

      /*
       * method + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(baseUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()) +
       * URLEncoder.encode("&" + ApplicationConstants.CONSUMER_KEY + "=\"" +
       * userFields.getConsumerKey() + "\"&" + ApplicationConstants.NONCE + "=\"" + nonce + "\"&" +
       * ApplicationConstants.SIGNATURE_METHOD_KEY + "=\"" +
       * ApplicationConstants.SIGNATURE_METHOD_VAL + "\"&" + ApplicationConstants.TIMESTAMP + "=\""
       * + timestamp + "\"&" + ApplicationConstants.TOKEN_ID + "=\"" + userFields.getTokenId() +
       * "\"&" + ApplicationConstants.VERSION_KEY + "=\"" + ApplicationConstants.VERSION_VAL + "\"",
       * StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
       */

      System.out.println("SignatureString = " + signatureString);
      // String signKey = URLEncoder.encode(userFields.getConsumerSecret(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
      // + "&" + URLEncoder.encode(userFields.getTokenSecret(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);// +
      // userFields.getTokenSecret();

      SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(
      (userFields.getConsumerSecret() + "&" ).getBytes(),
      "HmacSHA256");

  

      Mac m = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
      m.init(signingKey);
      m.update(signatureString.getBytes());
      byte[] res = m.doFinal();
      signature = Base64Coder.encodeLines(res);
      // URLEncoder.encode(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(res), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);


  /*
   * OAuthHmacSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSigner(); signer.clientSharedSecret =
   * userFields.getConsumerSecret(); signer.tokenSharedSecret = userFields.getTokenSecret();
   * GenericUrl urlgen = new GenericUrl(baseUrl); OAuthParameters oauthParameters = new
   * OAuthParameters(); oauthParameters.consumerKey = userFields.getConsumerKey();
   * oauthParameters.token = userFields.getTokenId(); oauthParameters.nonce = nonce;
   * oauthParameters.signatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA256"; oauthParameters.timestamp =
   * String.valueOf(timestamp); oauthParameters.version = ApplicationConstants.VERSION_VAL;
   * oauthParameters.signer = signer; oauthParameters.computeSignature(method, urlgen);
   * oauthParameters.realm = userFields.getAccountId();
   * 
   * signature = oauthParameters.signature;
   */

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Unable to append signature");
    }

System.out.println("signature=    " + signature);

String authHeaderString = "OAuth " + ApplicationConstants.REALM + "=\""
    + userFields.getAccountId() + "\"," + ApplicationConstants.CONSUMER_KEY + "=\""
    + userFields.getConsumerKey() + "\"," + ApplicationConstants.OAUTH_TOKEN + "=\""
    + userFields.getTokenId() + "\"," + ApplicationConstants.SIGNATURE_METHOD_KEY + "=\""
    + ApplicationConstants.SIGNATURE_METHOD_VAL + "\"," + ApplicationConstants.TIMESTAMP + "=\""
    + timestamp + "\"," + ApplicationConstants.NONCE + "=\"" + nonce + "\","
    + ApplicationConstants.VERSION_KEY + "=\"" + ApplicationConstants.VERSION_VAL + "\","
    + ApplicationConstants.SIGNATURE + "=\"" // + signature
    + URLEncoder.encode(signature.trim(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "\"";


System.out.println("authHeaderString = " + authHeaderString);

    return authHeaderString;
  }

  String getAlphaNumericString() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "").substring(0, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: sandbox or prod account?

Comment: It's sandbox account.   I change the name from 5252532-sb1 to 5252532_SB1 when providing account id. But does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try generate  the header in this order

```
 String header = "Authorization: OAuth ";
            header += "oauth_signature=\"" + ApplicationConstants.signature + "\",";
            header += "oauth_version=\"1.0\",";
            header += "oauth_nonce=\"" + ApplicationConstants.nonce + "\",";
            header += "oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\",";
            header += "oauth_consumer_key=\"" + .ApplicationConstants.ckey + "\",";
            header += "oauth_token=\"" + ApplicationConstants.tkey + "\",";
            header += "oauth_timestamp=\"" + ApplicationConstants.timestamp + "\",";
            header += "realm=\"ApplicationConstants.REALM\"";
```

Comment: i tried it but it did not work; still getting the same error. 
"Invalid login attempt. For more details, see the Login Audit Trail in the NetSuite UI at Setup > Users/Roles > User Management > View Login Audit Trail.","o:errorCode":"INVALID_LOGIN"}
at the page it says "InvalidSignature".